# How to add string in specific positions in geojson object

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have the below posted geojson mentioned in geojson_1 section below. i want to add to it `"geometry":{` and `}`, so that to appear as follows

```
{"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[1216374.67364018,6563498.44078949],[1216387.86261675,6563523.87797899],[1216397.66970116,6563548.2905649],[1216424.17569103,6563588.32082324],[1216458.19258303,6563622.16452455],[1216498.32084288,6563648.42909789],[1216542.90943577,6563666.03380959],[1216590.12376481,6563674.25425166],[1216638.02117068,6563672.7521636],[1216684.63088244,6563661.58935797],[1216728.03512655,6563641.225175],[1216752.29181681,6563626.67066235],[1216787.17700448,6563601.12371718],[1216816.83970763,6563569.63465531],[1216831.39332728,6563551.03748989],[1216838.2508451,6563541.8226918],[1216897.47283376,6563458.0765492],[1216918.74007329,6563421.44644481],[1216933.156564,6563381.60258193],[1216940.26085904,6563339.82061228],[1216939.82562707,6563297.43819918],[1216931.86491641,6563255.81218836],[1216907.60647856,6563170.91644364],[1216887.20280767,6563121.46139137],[1216856.24799209,6563077.86160203],[1216821.48046704,6563039.0529759],[1216799.23490474,6563017.28929875],[1216753.95673639,6562978.48086898],[1216737.29066155,6562965.4435638],[1216673.22488836,6562919.79826372],[1216644.73178636,6562899.22061724],[1216601.13622245,6562874.31962206],[1216562.32695185,6562857.3410734],[1216556.56069412,6562854.90900462],[1216549.97837146,6562852.23502385],[1216545.77480552,6562849.58841453],[1216504.75306873,6562829.03095075],[1216487.0229317,6562822.21187019],[1216482.65368148,6562820.3796627],[1216478.79578194,6562814.49158384],[1216462.95127963,6562793.04723497],[1216450.44559886,6562777.97698661],[1216448.65520854,6562774.19751598],[1216429.39331353,6562740.84427663],[1216404.99213055,6562711.06486155],[1216382.3528849,6562687.61801865],[1216357.97638417,6562665.64947943],[1216339.38004804,6562651.09634054],[1216299.24217837,6562625.743469],[1216254.86196793,6562608.94292463],[1216208.02902037,6562601.37212065],[1216160.63182011,6562603.33631786],[1216114.58159971,6562614.75632195],[1216071.73529105,6562635.17167463],[1216033.82066317,6562663.75921023],[1216002.36666225,6562699.36623124],[1215978.64176027,6562740.55696848],[1215963.60279766,6562785.67045603],[1215957.85638339,6562832.88749107],[1215961.63441126,6562880.30398198],[1215963.25125904,6562889.19806131],[1215964.03213898,6562893.28933659],[1215968.1319511,6562913.79137984],[1215972.03222389,6562937.19708669],[1215977.28745991,6563016.79645952],[1215971.45390521,6563048.0427099],[1215969.39172682,6563061.09023781],[1215963.73069651,6563104.75131293],[1215962.06592533,6563123.22251112],[1215960.00953034,6563163.6421848],[1215954.35640427,6563213.80082903],[1215954.63230125,6563269.34572034],[1215960.29082704,6563315.43307246],[1215970.70253119,6563361.57391952],[1215982.82982632,6563397.95907391],[1216001.20120538,6563439.38870108],[1216027.10825421,6563476.54992802],[1216059.60193364,6563508.08124916],[1216097.4918555,6563532.82739871],[1216139.38989254,6563549.8816932],[1216183.76104002,6563558.61926572],[1216228.97966418,6563558.71997125],[1216273.38907516,6563550.18012236],[1216287.1346647,6563546.13717455],[1216332.92682121,6563527.24586381],[1216373.78586258,6563499.1986745],[1216374.67364018,6563498.44078949]]]}}
```

to simpify it even more, i want to add `"geometry":{` right after the the first curly bracket, and the `}` at the very end

i attmepted the following:

```
asString = asString[:2] + "geometry:" + asString[2:]
asString = asString[:len(asString)] + "}" + asString[len(asString):]
```

but i am not getting the expected results

**geojson_1**:

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[1216374.67364018,6563498.44078949],[1216387.86261675,6563523.87797899],[1216397.66970116,6563548.2905649],[1216424.17569103,6563588.32082324],[1216458.19258303,6563622.16452455],[1216498.32084288,6563648.42909789],[1216542.90943577,6563666.03380959],[1216590.12376481,6563674.25425166],[1216638.02117068,6563672.7521636],[1216684.63088244,6563661.58935797],[1216728.03512655,6563641.225175],[1216752.29181681,6563626.67066235],[1216787.17700448,6563601.12371718],[1216816.83970763,6563569.63465531],[1216831.39332728,6563551.03748989],[1216838.2508451,6563541.8226918],[1216897.47283376,6563458.0765492],[1216918.74007329,6563421.44644481],[1216933.156564,6563381.60258193],[1216940.26085904,6563339.82061228],[1216939.82562707,6563297.43819918],[1216931.86491641,6563255.81218836],[1216907.60647856,6563170.91644364],[1216887.20280767,6563121.46139137],[1216856.24799209,6563077.86160203],[1216821.48046704,6563039.0529759],[1216799.23490474,6563017.28929875],[1216753.95673639,6562978.48086898],[1216737.29066155,6562965.4435638],[1216673.22488836,6562919.79826372],[1216644.73178636,6562899.22061724],[1216601.13622245,6562874.31962206],[1216562.32695185,6562857.3410734],[1216556.56069412,6562854.90900462],[1216549.97837146,6562852.23502385],[1216545.77480552,6562849.58841453],[1216504.75306873,6562829.03095075],[1216487.0229317,6562822.21187019],[1216482.65368148,6562820.3796627],[1216478.79578194,6562814.49158384],[1216462.95127963,6562793.04723497],[1216450.44559886,6562777.97698661],[1216448.65520854,6562774.19751598],[1216429.39331353,6562740.84427663],[1216404.99213055,6562711.06486155],[1216382.3528849,6562687.61801865],[1216357.97638417,6562665.64947943],[1216339.38004804,6562651.09634054],[1216299.24217837,6562625.743469],[1216254.86196793,6562608.94292463],[1216208.02902037,6562601.37212065],[1216160.63182011,6562603.33631786],[1216114.58159971,6562614.75632195],[1216071.73529105,6562635.17167463],[1216033.82066317,6562663.75921023],[1216002.36666225,6562699.36623124],[1215978.64176027,6562740.55696848],[1215963.60279766,6562785.67045603],[1215957.85638339,6562832.88749107],[1215961.63441126,6562880.30398198],[1215963.25125904,6562889.19806131],[1215964.03213898,6562893.28933659],[1215968.1319511,6562913.79137984],[1215972.03222389,6562937.19708669],[1215977.28745991,6563016.79645952],[1215971.45390521,6563048.0427099],[1215969.39172682,6563061.09023781],[1215963.73069651,6563104.75131293],[1215962.06592533,6563123.22251112],[1215960.00953034,6563163.6421848],[1215954.35640427,6563213.80082903],[1215954.63230125,6563269.34572034],[1215960.29082704,6563315.43307246],[1215970.70253119,6563361.57391952],[1215982.82982632,6563397.95907391],[1216001.20120538,6563439.38870108],[1216027.10825421,6563476.54992802],[1216059.60193364,6563508.08124916],[1216097.4918555,6563532.82739871],[1216139.38989254,6563549.8816932],[1216183.76104002,6563558.61926572],[1216228.97966418,6563558.71997125],[1216273.38907516,6563550.18012236],[1216287.1346647,6563546.13717455],[1216332.92682121,6563527.24586381],[1216373.78586258,6563499.1986745],[1216374.67364018,6563498.44078949]]]}
```

Comment: Is geojson_1 a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that geojson_1 is available as a string in which case:

```
import json

output = {'geometry': json.loads(geojson_1)}
```

...will give you a dictionary with the structure you need.

Comment: i am now getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' any idea please

Comment: +1, this is a lot cleaner than fetching and then reinserting it in itself. Actually seems to be the perfect solution here!

Comment: @LetsamrIt There is no *get()* in either my code or yours (that you've shown)

Answer (score 0):

I get the expected result using the following:

```
 '{"geometry":' + d + "}"
```

It adds the string `{"geometry":` to the string d and at the end `}`.

The variable `d`is:
`d = '{"type":"Polygon","co (rest of json) ,6563498.44078949]]]}'`

Or you can use the `json` library for this:

```
import json
data = json.loads(d) # note d is the same string as above, this can also be from a file or read file using json.load(FILE)

# Create your new object:
result = {'geometry': data}

# print you new json:
print( json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

*edit*:

```
 '"geometry":{' + d + "}"
```

Note that you get a string starting with geometry and a `{` and directly another `{` from you input json. This is not a correct dictionary nor a proper json format.

Result:

```
'"geometry":{{"type":"Polygon", ... ,6563498.44078949]]]}}'
```

(the dots are just the rest of your original json.

Comment: but i do not want to add { at the beginning. i want to add '"geometry":{' at the second position of the geojson mentioned iin the section geojson_1..and at the end i want to add '}'

Comment: Oke, then you have to change the position of the bracket, but the result stays the same (but you probably end with an improper json). I will add an edit

Comment: @LetsamrIt I changed my answer, but the first two methods create your expected output and what you are asking for does not.

Comment: @LetsamrIt there is literally no difference between `'{"geometry": ' + '{"type"...'` and `'{' + '"geometry": {' + '"type"'` here

Answer (score 0):

It looks like plain `json` data, or a string representation of a `dict` (they wouldn't be any different in this case), did you consider wrapping the returned data in a new `dict` rather than manipulating it as a string?

```py
import json

# Assume this returns the geojson as text
geojson = json.loads(get_geojson())
geojson = {"geometry": geojson}
print(json.dumps(geojson))
```